# handle language identification

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, database-design

In a multilanguage website, should I reference the language with numbers or keywords?

For example, let's say an english person selects a service from a list of services, the list of services will be in english, while if a spanish person selects from a list of services, the list will be in spanish.

The list of services is selected from a table in a database, each service has a unique number to identify it, and something to identify in what language the service is written.
What I'm asking is, which is better. To use a number to identify the language, or to use a language code?

Example:

hypothetical table of services:

```
id | service_id | service | lang
------------------------------------
0  | cooking    | 1       | en
1  | driving    | 2       | en
2  | singing    | 3       | en
3  | running    | 4       | en
4  | cocinar    | 1       | es
5  | conducir   | 2       | es
6  | cantar     | 3       | es
7  | correr     | 4       | es
```

VS

```
id | service_id | service | lang
------------------------------------
0  | cooking    | 1       | 1
1  | driving    | 2       | 1
2  | singing    | 3       | 1
3  | running    | 4       | 1
4  | cocinar    | 1       | 2
5  | conducir   | 2       | 2
6  | cantar     | 3       | 2
7  | correr     | 4       | 2
```

Where I give a numerical id to every language

I can see the language code approach makes the database more human readable, but why should it really matter if the server handles it all anyway, where numbers are easier for the server, but then I would have to give a number to every language.

So which approach do you think is better and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would almost always normalize such things, but this may be a rare exception for the following reasons:

1. An nchar(2) column would only occupy 4 bytes, which is the same as an int column. Therfore, performance should not be impacted, especially if you set the coalation to ordinal.
2. The two-character language codes are in international standards which are *extremely* unlikely to ever be changed. So massive updates should not be an issue.

So the arguments for normalization do not really apply in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the coalation tip, would never have thought of it. So in case of languages, codes are better after all.

Comment: +1 I agree with Jeffrey's advice - use the standard codes. The normalization comment doesn't make any sense however. Whether to use numbers or language codes for languages has nothing to do with normalization.

Comment: @Jeffrey should I consider using 5 byte codes instead, like 'en_US'?

Comment: @dportas - Yes, I realized after I wrote this that "normalization" wasn't the correct term. What I was thinking of, rather, is that I would normally use an artificial key rather than a natural key, and that this is a rare case where a natural key would be appropriate. (I know some advocate natural keys is many places, but that is not my feelings on the matter in most cases.)

Comment: I let the wording stand, since if an artificial key were to be used, then the effect would be the same as normalization. That is, many instances of "en" would be replaced by a single instance referenced by a numeric key.

Comment: @YuriKolovsky - Whether to use the longer code would depend on whether you wish to localize the application to a region within each language. If you do that, then you will probably want to use the bare language code as a fallback. Dealing with those issues might require an entirely different design. I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

There is an [ISO standardized set of language codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639). I'd just go with using those like example 1.  You should probabbly have a secondary table that lists the short 2/3 digit codes to the long spelled out version as well.

Comment: +1 An iso_languages table within your database is a very good idea. Using the 2-letter code to join to it as in the first example is fine.